# SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) install postgresql93 uninstallable providers

Tags: dependencies, suse, postgresql, zypper

I'm trying to install postresql93 but I have a problem with package dependencies

```
Problem: postgresql93-9.3.5-2.1.14.x86_64 requires systemd, but this requirement cannot be provided  uninstallable providers: systemd-210-25.5.4.i586[openSUSE:13.2] 
               systemd-210-25.5.4.x86_64[openSUSE:13.2] 
Solution 1:   
Following actions will be done:   
    deinstallation of sysvinit-2.86-215.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of ivman-0.6.14-201.31.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of libgphoto2-2.4.3-3.25.73.x86_64
    deinstallation of libzypp-9.16.4-0.5.2.x86_64
    deinstallation of xorg-x11-server-7.4-27.70.76.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of xorg-x11-driver-video-radeonhd-1.3.0_20100512_80ba041-1.8.55.x86_64
    deinstallation of libgphoto2-lang-2.4.3-3.25.73.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-ncurses-pkg-2.17.20-0.5.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-pkg-bindings-2.17.58-0.5.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of zypper-1.6.178-0.5.3.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-2.17.121.1-0.5.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-packager-2.17.98-0.5.73.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-bootloader-2.17.86-0.5.20.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-online-update-2.17.21-0.1.89.noarch
    deinstallation of suseRegister-1.4-1.26.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-registration-2.17.35.4-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-wagon-2.17.32.4-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-add-on-2.17.28-0.5.95.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-add-on-creator-2.17.15-0.5.93.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-audit-laf-2.17.10-0.2.18.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-autofs-2.17.1-0.1.61.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-boot-server-2.14.0-276.38.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-ca-management-2.17.23-0.5.25.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-dhcp-server-2.17.6-0.4.2.21.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-dirinstall-2.17.4-0.5.238.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-firewall-2.17.11-0.5.92.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-inetd-2.17.3-1.53.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-instserver-2.17.6-0.2.1.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-irda-2.17.3-0.1.85.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-iscsi-client-2.17.34-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-iscsi-server-2.17.10-0.7.3.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-isns-2.17.2-0.2.2.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-metapackage-handler-0.8.7-1.34.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-nis-server-2.17.2-1.53.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-ntp-client-2.17.14-1.10.14.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-pam-2.17.3-0.5.211.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-power-management-2.17.7-0.1.84.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-repair-2.17.11-0.5.109.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-runlevel-2.17.9-0.7.3.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-samba-client-2.17.21-0.5.186.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-security-2.17.15-0.5.214.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-slp-server-2.17.4-0.2.48.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-sshd-2.17.2-1.21.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-sudo-2.17.3-1.53.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-support-2.17.19-2.1.59.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-sysconfig-2.17.0-1.38.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-fingerprint-reader-2.17.7-0.1.201.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-mouse-2.16.1-19.38.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-nis-client-2.17.8-0.1.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-printer-2.17.63-0.2.43.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-profile-manager-2.17.2-0.7.5.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-squid-2.17.11-0.3.46.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-tune-2.17.7-1.28.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-update-2.17.23-0.5.40.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-users-2.17.51-0.5.166.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-backup-2.17.14-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-ftp-server-2.17.9-0.5.2.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-http-server-2.17.15-0.5.2.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-kdump-2.17.22-0.4.3.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-kerberos-client-2.17.15-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-ldap-2.17.7-0.5.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-ldap-client-2.17.35-0.5.2.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-ldap-server-2.17.44-0.5.1.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-mail-2.17.6-0.13.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-nfs-server-2.17.8-0.2.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-restore-2.17.7-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-samba-server-2.17.14-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-storage-2.17.127.2-0.5.3.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-tftp-server-2.17.2-0.2.3.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-vm-2.17.10-0.5.42.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-network-2.17.182.12-0.5.11.x86_64
    deinstallation of yast2-nfs-client-2.17.14-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-registration-branding-SLE-2.17.35.4-0.5.1.noarch
    deinstallation of yast2-online-update-frontend-2.17.21-0.1.89.noarch
 Solution 2: do not install postgresql93-9.3.5-2.1.14.x86_64
 Solution 3: do not install postgresql93-9.3.5-2.1.14.x86_64
 Solution 4: break postgresql93-9.3.5-2.1.14.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/3/4/c] (c):
```

What are the recommended steps to attempt here? If I go with 1 will all the packages be removed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're mixing SLES 11 with openSUSE 13.2 RPM's. "systemd" is not available in SLES 11, so trying to install an RPM which has a mandatory dependency to systemd will fail.

UPDATE:

The suggested way to solve this problem would be to get/use a license for SLES 11. After registering your system with that licence you could automatically configure online update repositories that are maintained by SUSE. These repositories contain a Postgresql version which should perfectly fit.

There's also an repository in the open Build Service (for SLES 11 SP3), but it's not maintained anymore, I think. At least the build is broken.